# Stack Exchange Profile shows question as favorite when it was not favorited

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, profile-page, bookmarks

My Stack Exchange profile page is showing a question marked as favorite, when I actually only downvoted the question. In the question itself, you can see that it has been not been marked as a favorite by anyone.

**Question:**
[Generate random number every x seconds and display it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070567/generate-random-number-every-x-seconds-and-display-it)

**Screenshot of my Stack Exchange profile page:**
[image]

---

This entry, however, does **not** show up in my Stack Overflow profile page.

---

**Update**

I don't know if any of the mods/admins took care of it, but the entry is gone now. The last thing I tried was [Caled's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174112/stack-exchange-profile-shows-question-as-favorite-when-it-was-not-favorited#comment520439_174112) of adding and removing the question from favorite (with a few seconds pause in between).

Comment: Even better, according to your screenshot and profile there are 0 users who've favourited that question :-).

Comment: Did you favorite then unfavorite it? Perhaps this is a caching issue?

Comment: @Caleb I don't recall ever favoriting the question (maybe possibly by mistake when trying to downvote). I just tried to favorite/unfavorite, however, it still shows in my SE profile. How long does it take for the SE profile to update?